# C# list sort with OR condition

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm trying to sort a list that comes from my database. If all fields in my `OrderFunds` column are `null`, I want to sort by another column. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

This is my code:

```
List<Fund> funds = await fundSupervisor.List().Where(fund => fund.IsActive)
                                              .OrderBy(fund => fund.OrderFunds)
```

Or, my `OrderBy` clause can allow `null` values. That would help me too.

Comment: You probably want [`.ThenBy(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.thenby)

Comment: `OrderBy` should not have problems with nulls, however, there's a problem in your code. Looks like this `List()` method possibly retrieves records from the database and materializes everything into a list. Consecutive `Where` and `OrderBy` look like they work on an in-memory list. This is a huge waste or server resources!

Comment: _If **all** OrderFunds are null, I want so sort by another column_ - you simply need to look for `if(list.Any(item => item.OrderFunds != null)) { OrderByOrderFunds } else { OrderBySomethingElse}`. Then, ordering is done in memory

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution

```
List<Fund> funds = fundSupervisor
.Where(w => w.IsActive)
.OrderBy(w => w.OrderFunds)
.ThenBy(w => w.OtherField).ToList();
```

`ThenBy()` allows you specify other fields to sort your list.

Comment: I think the title of the post is bad as this is NOT an OR condition. But in the OP's situation when the OrderBy field values are all NULL the ThenBy wins.

Comment: @Grandizer what you said is true!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to sort totally different if, and only if **all** columns are null, you need to check that in advance.

```
List<Fund> funds = await fundSupervisor.List().Where(fund => fund.IsActive)
if(funds .Any(item => item.OrderFunds != null))
    funds = funds.OrderBy(fund => fund.OrderFunds);
else
    funds = funds.OrderBy(fund => fund.SomethingElse);
```

Otherwise, if you want to sort by another value if `OrderFunds` is `null`, then you can simply use a condition inside the `OrderBy`.

```
var orderedFunds = funds.OrderBy(fund => fund.OrderFunds ?? SomeOtherValue);
```

If you want to sort by another value as secondary sorting, use a `ThenBy`. That sorts all values by the `ThenBy`-value if there are multiple same values in the `OrderBy`-operation.

```
var orderedThenByFunds = funds.OrderBy(fund => fund.OrderFunds).ThenBy(fund => fund.SomeOtherValue);
```

Consider that these lines are different:
Say you have 3 items (assumed `OrderFunds` is `int?`:

```
Fund1 { OrderFunds = 1, SomeOtherValue = 8 }
Fund2 { OrderFunds = 3, SomeOtherValue = 6 }
Fund3 { OrderFunds = null, SomeOtherValue = 4 }
Fund4 { OrderFunds = null, SomeOtherValue = 2 }
```

Then `orderedFunds` would return Fund1(1), Fund4(2[SomeOtherValue]), Fund2(3), Fund3(4[SomeOtherValue]) and `orderedThenByFunds` would return Fund1(1,8), Fund2(3,8), Fund4(null,2), Fund3(null,2). The values in braces are the values ordered by.